# Git - [includeIf] multiple gitconfigs not working

Tags: git

I'm trying to get multiple gitconfigs working on my repos use `[includeIf]`.
I have a regular repo at: *~/Development/Business/work/* and a test repo at *~/Development/Business/test/*.

The following global gitconfig and specific gitconfigs are as follow:

*~.gitconfig*

```
[user]
    name = First Last
    email = email@email.com
    
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Development/Business/test/"]
    path = ~/Development/Business/test/.gitconfig
```

*~/Development/Business/test/.gitconfig*

```
[user]
    name = First Last
    email = test@email.com
```

My HOME environmental variable is `C:\`

When I run `git config user.email` on the path `~/Development/Business/test/repo1` I receive the following output:

```
git config user.email
email@email.com
```

However, the expected outcome should be:

```
git config user.email
test@email.com
```

When I run `git config --show-origin user.email` the output is

> file:C://.gitconfig     email@email.com

Shouldn't it be pointing to *`test/.gitconfig`*?

Comment: Sorry, but why do you have a `--show-origin` command? I don't have it `git version 2.26.2`

Comment: @trallnag clearly the author meant `git config --show-origin`. There are no subcommands that start with a `--` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This feature [comes from Git 2.14 (Q3 2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43621480/6309), which includes [some tests](https://github.com/git/git/blob/86f951570839e241cfa8effbe195674193693a7f/t/t1305-config-include.sh#L235-L262):

In case ~ is not properly replaces by %HOME%, try and use `/C/` in your paths to check if this works better (for testing).