# Git repo not found unless username is added to url

Tags: git, github

I recently added a conditional statement to my .gitconfig I order to use two git profiles. However, now I must append my username to every repo url in order for it to be found.

Added to `.gitconfig`

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/"]
        path = ~/work/.gitconfig
```

When you copy and paste a url **directly from Github** the url looks like this

```
https://github.com/user123/my-amazing-project.git
```

So if I forgot to add the username in while I clone it (which I usually do) I need to run;

```
git remote add origin https://user123@github.com/user123/my-amazing-project.git
```

Is there anyway to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the user to the URL should not be linked to the [conditional include](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43621480/6309), but rather be the consequence of using a `git config credential helper`.

That would allow the HTTPS credentials cache helper to distinguish between `userABC@github.com` and `user123@github.com`

And the command would not be `git remote add`, but:

```
cd /path/to/repo/already/cloned
git remote set-url origin https://user123@github.com/user123/my-amazing-project.git
```