# How can I switch github user in Git Bash for Windows?

Tags: git, git-bash

I have two GitHub accounts and want to push to a repository with one of them, lets call it account **A**.
But the thing is my Git Bash for Windows always push with the other, the account **B**.

I believe that happens because the first time I downloaded Git Bash (long time ago) I configured my user to be the account **B**, but I can't figure out how to switch them.

I unistalled Git Bash and installed again, this time with no credential help feature and even went to Control Panel and excluded the generic credentials regarding GitHub but still, everytime I commit, it is with the **B** account.

In fact, after I reinstalled and excluded the generic credentials, the Git Bash asked me to enter my Git user and password before pushing, I entered my account **A** and, surprise surprise, in the end the commit was still made with account **B**.
I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commit "made as B" have nothing to do with user credentials.

Those commits *author* are from `git config user.name`/`git config user.email`

Change those settings in your repository, and you will see new commits pushed as B.

As [Philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717372/philippe) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65726215/how-can-i-switch-github-user-in-git-bash-for-windows/65727565#comment116213074_65727565), you can also manage different user identities through conditional `.gitconfig` files ([with Git 2.13+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43621480/6309))

Comment: And I could add that if you have this problem for multiple repositories, you could have a look at 'conditional include' in '.gitconfig' file.

Comment: @Philippe Good point. I have included your suggestion in the answer for more visibility.