# Dual SSH key setup pains

Tags: git, github, ssh

I set up two SSH keys corresponding to two separate GitHub accounts and the ergonomics of my set up aren't quite working for me.

Somewhere (I can't remember where), I have it set up such that if I'm in the `dev` folder, it commits with my zackshapiro account and if I'm in my `other-dev` folder, it commits with my alt_account.

Here's my `~.ssh/config`:

```
Host zackshapiro
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host alt_account
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UseKeychain yes
```

And my `.zshrc`:

```
alias ssh-personal="ssh-add -D; ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
alias ssh-alt="ssh-add -D; ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_ed25519"
```

What's become annoying though are problems with `git clone`, and `git push` primarily, where I get errors such as these:

When I `git push`, I'll get

```
fatal: The current branch main has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin main
```

And I have to do `git push git@github.com:{account}/{project}` to get the code to push up.

Similarly with `git clone`, I can't just do `git clone {and paste the link directly from GH}`.

I have to do `git clone git@github.com:/{account}/{project}`

I'd really like to fix the ergonomics of this so I don't have to search my history, change the text of a previous push or clone and can generally move faster.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> fatal: The current branch main has no upstream branch.
> To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
>
>    git push --set-upstream origin main
> ```

That "ergonomic" was fixed with [Git 2.37 (Q2 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401899/6309), which allows you to forget about `--track` or `--set-upstream-to` with:

```
git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true
```

A `git push` would automatically link the current local and remote branch.

If you can upgrade your Git to 2.37 or the (current) latest 2.38.1, said push would be easier.

---

> Somewhere (I can't remember where), I have it set up such that if I'm in the `dev` folder, it commits with my `zackshapiro` account and if I'm in my `other-dev` folder, it commits with my `alt_account`.

This is usually done with [`git config` `includeIf` directives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43621480/6309) (Git 2.13, Q2 2017).